# Wordpress htaccess rewrite to subfolder by specific requests

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I tried different rules in htaccess and the solutions I found on stackoverflow doesn't work. My Problem: A Wordpress site with a specific page found under https://www.example.com/konfigurator . At this page an embedded app is loaded async by javascript. When the site gets a request under the /konfigurator e.g. /konfigurator/jeweler-finder it needs to load the app with the slug /jeweler-finder. I tried this htaccess code and it results the Wordpress 404 page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /

# App
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^konfigurator/. /konfigurator/ [L]

#Wordpress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions on this problem!

Comment: How is this "app" loaded? So, this is completely outside of WordPress? Although you state that you have "A Wordpress site with a specific page found under /konfigurator" - soo, this IS WordPress?

Comment: The app is simply loaded by javascript call in a div. The /konfigurator page is hard coded as a custom template page without the wordpress overhead. The call of this page and the rendering of the app works fine. But the navigation inside the app needs to be routed to app root via htaccess.

Comment: Ok, if we go to example.com/konfigurator/jeweler-finder/ to wthat url we need to redirect ? example.com/?appurl=jeweler-finder ?

Comment: to example.com/konfigurator ... the js app reads the slug /jeweler-finder and reacts (loads stuff async)

Comment: How you select that slug ? Field , dropdown ? just use on change method ?

Comment: _"The /konfigurator page is hard coded as a custom template page without the wordpress overhead."_ - but still delivered _by_ Wordpress? _"the js app reads the slug /jeweler-finder and reacts (loads stuff async)"_ - does that app need to be able to load _static_ assets from below that `/konfigurator` path?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. The solution was: I removed the wordpress page "konfigurator" and set a directory "/konfigurator" instead. The code for the app is placed in the /konfigurator/index.php file now. This works:

```
# App
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^konfigurator/. /konfigurator/ [L]

#Wordpress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. "The code for the app is placed in the `/konfigurator/index.php`" - Then you should be rewriting directly to that file, not the directory (which then requires an additional rewrite by mod_dir). ie. `RewriteRule ^konfigurator/. /konfigurator/index.php [L]`. (Presumably, you've also overridden WPs default behaviour of maintaining the `.htaccess` file? Changed perms or something?)

Comment: While the app is a third party app it crashed when rewrite to the index.php. This way it works, I did not changes anything else

Comment: Hhhmmm, it shouldn't have "crashed" - there shouldn't have been any difference?! (Assuming you also kept the preceding _conditions_.)